# Electron Packager: Created .Exe Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I'm creating a react application that I want to package up into an executable. I just figured out how to open the app via electron, but am now having trouble packaging it up into an application. When I run `npm run electronTest` (code seen below), the application runs perfectly. But when I run `package-win": "electron-packager . myApp --platform=win32 --arch=x64"` the created .Exe file only opens a React looking application window and doesn't show anything. Not really sure where i'm going wrong here.

Code:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "json-server": "json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run json-server\"",
    "electronTest": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run json-server\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . JIVES --platform=win32 --arch=x64"
  },
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: [image]

Comment: What does `React looking application window` mean?

Comment: @Phix I added a photo. First time ever doing this so wasn't sure how to explain.

Comment: open console and see what's going on. I bet that js paths are off

Comment: @eggy how would I go about doing that? I guess one thought I had was when I run it successfully with `npm run electronTest`, i'm telling it the script I want it to run to get everything going. When I package it up and create the .exe, what script is called to start the application on double click of the .exe?

Comment: View > Toggle Developer Tools. Or you could use shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+I`

Comment: Thanks @Eggy! Figured it out. in my `main.js` I have `mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')`. But the script `"electronTest": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run json-server\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",` isn't being ran to set things up on localhost. Is there a way to call a script in `main.js`? Or another hack so that the "setup" script is ran first and foremost?

Comment: You shouldn't run server in electron, it's a no-no. If you have a build system set up use it first to create production build. And instead of loading server url, load file(`BrowserWindow.loadFile`). It's common to switch it with env variable. With webpack you could do something like this: `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? win.loadFile(join(__dirname, './path/to/index.html')) : win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')`

Comment: Futhermore in electronjs there are 2 kinds of precesses: main process, and render process. And nothing else really. Your json server is running outside of electron in dev mode. So either, develop it separatly, and deploy it somewhere on the web. Or use it inside electron main process(but that's really bad, performance wise, and you shouldn't do it). Alternatively you could run hidden browser window to run your server(that would be better for performance), but it seems like bad idea to start with(you can alredy communicate http like through ipc). Why do you need server in the first place?

Comment: @Eggy, i'm still getting used to the terminology of this stuff, so I wanted to confirm what you just said. So instead of utilizing `localhost`, I should run `npm run build` to create a build version of the application. That creates the `index.html` file I'll use. Correct? I guess i'm just a little confused on how the rest of the `electronTest` code is ran though. Such as the `npm run json-server`part

Comment: It's not, npm scripts only run inside you repo, once it's built, its standalone code. Think of it as binary someone donwloads and install on their machine. If you absolutely need json-server, use it programmatically from main process, but that's bad idea to start with(depending on workload it will lag your BrowserWindows)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, you are using `json-server` as cli, and it's **not** going to run when you build binaries through electron-packager. Running json-server(or any server for that matter) is just pointless because you can already communicate with main process through [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderer). But if you want that abstraction, you can run it, just use it programatically **inside** you electronjs code. In main process(that's a bad idea, for performance reasons, although json-server should be quite lightweight) or in hidden renderer process with nodejs enabled.

per documentations it would look something like this:

```js
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()
 
server.use(middlewares)
server.use(router)
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
})
```